# iOS configuration profile for ad-hoc/Devices wifi network issue

Tags: ios, wifi, configuration-profile, apple-configurator

I've been researching this issue for quite a while now without making any progress.

I was trying to create a wifi configuration profile, using the Apple configurator tool, to enable iOS devices to auto-join or remember my custom ad-hoc network.

I quickly realised that there isn't an option on the configurator to create a profile that refers to an ad-hoc network. Currently my network appears on the iPhone in the wifi tab under the 'Devices' header and not under the "Choose a network" header.

If I select to join my ad-hoc network, it connects without problems and it receives an IP address, I can interact with the network and all is working according to plan.

When I enable the wifi and the iPhone traces potential wifi networks around me, it pops up the dialog to choose one which doesn't include the 'Devices' network list of choices.

The configurator tool has only options that correspond to access points or hotspots. It doesn't mention anything for "Devices" networks.

It is imperative for my commercial application that I create a configuration profile to enable iPhones that have my app installed to auto-join this ad-hoc network.

I realise that the delivery of the profile to the device is a whole other issue but there are several methods to do it after the installation process.

Any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

John R.

Comment: To do what you want I think you need to look at the WAC service available under the MFi program

Comment: Thanks for that, had no idea that such program existed by apple.